# React + Express + Twitter API to Heroku get 405 Not Allowed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, twitter

I'm new in React and Express, and i'm trying to create small app that will show Twitter Timeline for specific User(username taken from text-input).
It's work locally, but on Heroku i have an Error in method: 'POST' 
405(Not Allowed)

```
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
            fetch('./', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({name: event.target.elements.name.value})
            }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(twitter => this.setState({twitter}));
        }
```

Full code here https://github.com/oslyvtc/react-express-heroku

You can see error here https://polar-fjord-91508.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Try to remove . from your fetch statement ('/').

Comment: @Frrank Still the same

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys. As i thought it was just misspelling issue.
I named Procfile.txt instead of Procfile, thats why heroku didn't run node server.js